# How to copy folder as root in Lubuntu 14.04 terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, lubuntu

I am trying to copy the b43 folder into the /lib/firmware folder. I know I asked this before, but this is on a completely different OS. I can't seem to launch nautilus using `sudo nautilus` or `gksu nautilus` .

Comment: `gksu pcmanfm` if gksu is not installed, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install gksu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change the directory where the file is located

```
cd <location of b43>
```

in your case

```
cd Desktop
```

and you can copy the folder by

```
sudo cp -a b43  /lib/firmware
```

Comment: The b43 folder is on the desktop. And for some reason the full path for /lib/firmware is actually home/jake/lib/firmware, therefore the path being in the home folder for my account, which is where it should not be going. It should be going to the main file system path /lib/firmware. What would be the full path for the main file system? If I use the command you gave me I get `cp: cannot stat 'b43' : No such file or directory` since the file wasn't being launched of the desktop. Can you edit the post? I see your edit, but I still get the same message.

Comment: i think to copy files inside the home/jake/lib/firmware wont need `sudo`

Comment: The /lib/firmware needs to be in the main file system. I was saying i was incorrect with the /home/jake/lib/firmware, I am not sure how to get to the root file system folders.

Answer (score 1):

If b43 is a file on the desktop and you need to copy the file to /lib/firmware, run the following command:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43 /lib/firmware
```

If b43 is a file at /home/jake/lib/firmware and you need to copy the file to /lib/firmware, run the following command:

```
sudo cp ~/lib/firmware/b43 /lib/firmware
```

Additionally, if you need to use the file manager instead, run the following command in Lubuntu:

```
gksu pcmanfm
```

if gksu is not installed, you may need to run the following command in an open terminal first to install gksu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

if you don't like pcmanfm and you want to install nautilus, you can do so with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD never run GUI programs as just sudo, I learned the hard way. It has a tendency a lot of times of driving you crazy, by changing ownership on config files in your home directory

To get nautilus as root, use

```
sudo -i nautilus
```

this should use root's environment and not screw up your config files

The only reason I can see that you wouldn't be able to open nautilus is if you have a different desktop environment, i.e. LXDE or KDE or something like that, basically non-GNOME based. In that case the DE has it's own file manager

EDIT:
Got my answer, saw you tagged lubuntu which is LXDE so that has PCManFM as the default File Manager, so you should be able to run (can't test as I'm not on LXDE)

```
sudo -i pcmanfm
```

Comment: OP is using (or trying to use) gksu which is the proper way to not screw things up.

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @mchid that is true but he also said he tried running sudo nautilus. I was pointing out on that point

Comment: @A.B. I mentioned in the edit that being he is on LXDE he doesn't have nautilus and should instead run pcmanfm